# e2e tests with protractor - how to return selected menu item from function inside page model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I have a menu `<ul class="menu">` with items `<li>`. In e2e tests I use page model.

In a spec I want to call page model function which:

- check that only one menu item has class `selected`
- return its index

My code

```
describe('Main screen and global navigation', () => {
    class MainPage {
        load() {
            browser.get('');
        }

        getMainMenuActiveItemIndex(): number {
            let list = element.all(by.css('ul.menu li'));
            // iterate somehow
            return 0;
        }

        navigate(itemClass: string) {
            let menuItem = element(by.css('ul.menu li.' + itemClass));
            menuItem.click();
        }
    }

    let p = new MainPage();

    beforeEach(function () {
        p.load();
    });
    it('should navigate to subpages', () => {
        expect(p.getMainMenuActiveItemIndex()).toBe(0);
        p.navigate('invoices');
        expect(p.getMainMenuActiveItemIndex()).toBe(1);
    });
})
```

I know that `element...` return promise. But I don't know how to return result of this promise from function i.e. how to resolve promise before returning function value.

Or maybe should I return promise from function instead of number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to do it,

```
 getMainMenuActiveItemIndex() {
     return element.all(by.css('ul.menu li')).getAttribute('class').then((classArray) => {
          for(let i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++){
            if (classArray[i].indexOf('selected') > -1){
                 return i;
              }
          }
          return -1; //if none of the li element have class `selected` then return -1
       })
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea on Typescript. But from the error, it is clear that you need to change the return type of your method from `number` to `promise`

Answer (score 0):

Just return the promise. Protractor's **expect()** will resolve it automatically. You dont have to give then()

Feel free to ask for clarifications

**Edit 1:**  i guess you got the answer from @sudharsa. But i suggest you to use filter function instead of then function in getMainMenuActiveItemIndex()

Comment: what would be sample implementation of `getMainMenuActiveItemIndex` ?